# Generalized Sum over Product Inequality : Related to Cauchy Schwarz's and AM-GM Inequality.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Consider set $S = \left \{ a_i \mid  1 \leq i \leq n \right \}$ where $a_i \in  \mathbb{R}$ and fixed integer $t$

I do not know whether the following inequality is true or not:

$$\sum_{P \subset S, \left | P \right | = t}\left ( {\prod_{j=1}^{\left | P \right |} a_j}\right ) \leqslant  \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{\left | S \right |} \frac{a_i}{n}\right )^{t} \binom{n}{t}$$

i.e. approximating each $a_i$ by the average $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} {\frac{a_i}{n}}$ and with $\binom{n}{t}$ number of such sets P

For example: $S = \left \{ a,b,c \right \}$ and $t=2$, The above inequality states :

$ab+bc+ca \leqslant {3\left ( \frac{a+b+c}{3} \right )}^{2}$

I am able to conclude the validity for this example as follows:

$2(ab+bc+ca) = (a+b+c)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$

Now using *Cauchy Schwarz's Inequality*, we have  $ (a+b+c)^2\leqslant 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$

$2(ab+bc+ca) \leqslant (a+b+c)^2 - \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}$

$\therefore ab+bc+ca \leqslant {3\left ( \frac{a+b+c}{3} \right )}^{2}$

Please, tell if this inequality is true for general case or not?
Thank you. and Sorry for the bad *title* for the question (Please suggest some).

Comment: The inequaity $$ab+bc+ca \leqslant {3\left ( \frac{a+b+c}{3} \right )}^{2}$$ is just Chebyshev ;)

Comment: I think you mean "Chebyshev's sum inequality" ? Thanks, I learned new inequality today :)

Comment: But, again this inequality holds for a,b,c,d and t = 2 also, which we may not get using Chebyshev's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all $a_i$ are assumed to be non-negative then it is an immediate consequence of [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality). In fact,

$$
S_t = \frac{\sum_\limits{P \subset S,  | P  | = t}\left ( {\prod_\limits{a \in P} a}\right )}{ \binom{n}{t}} \, ,
$$
satisfies
$$
\sqrt[t]{S_t} \le S_1 = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \, .
$$

Without that assumption  it does not hold in general. A counter-example
is $S = \{ 2, -1, -1 \}$ and $t = 3$.